# Proper error catching when dealing with multiple elements in puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

I am navigating through a site and have a nested structure like this:

```
if (deliveryTab) {
        let deliveryButton = await self.page.$(
            "button#shopping-selector-shop-context-intent-delivery"
        );
        if (deliveryButton) {
            await deliveryButton.click();
```

I try to check if each button/element is not null before going to the next step but this starts creating a large amount of nested ifs. I was thinking of surrounding everything in a large try...catch or using a try..catch on every possible element I am dealing with. This leads me to believe that maybe my approach isn't good.

If I was running on a slow network, using waitForSelector() with shorter timeouts might throw an error even if an element was about to load, but I am also afraid that using page.$("selector") will return null on a slow network as well even after waitForNavigation. I was wondering if there are any elegant solutions/practices to making sure my app can handle most errors / changes in the site I am traversing.

Comment: That looks like an old fashioned html-only or jquery website so the elements will be there right away even on a slow network.

Comment: I want to say that isn't the case but I am not too experienced to really tell. There are certain forms that open up when I click on something and they become null if I try to query select them after closing them. It looks to be more of a single page application.

Comment: The easiest way to tell is to open your network tab and search for the element, if it's in the main response and not a xhr then you don't have to wait for it. If it's in neither then you have a react/angular/vue situation

Comment: What do I do if it it's created with those frameworks? I am assuming it's angular because I am seeing a lot of ng-ifs in the html. Are my options limited?

Comment: In that case it's angular and you will have to `waitFor` everything before clicking.